# Looking for suggestions on workaround for java.net.URL inconsistency/bug

Tags: java

The following code exposes the bug, I know I could just tail the the results of getFile() & getPath() but I'm looking for something a big more elegant and **robust**.  I want to be able to walk the folders in both the containing jar by default and with user selected/configuration paths to find & load resources.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class UrlBug {

UrlBug() {
    try {
        final URL resourceRoot = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".");
        System.out.println(resourceRoot.getFile());
        System.out.println(resourceRoot.getPath());
        System.out.println(resourceRoot.toURI());
        System.out.println(resourceRoot.toExternalForm());
        System.out.println(resourceRoot.toString());
        new URL(resourceRoot.getFile());
    } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new UrlBug();
}
}
```

The output produced below with 'bug'

```
/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/.../target/classes/            <-- Malformed filename
/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/.../target/classes/            <-- Malformed path
file:/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/.../target/classes/
file:/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/.../target/classes/
file:/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/.../target/classes/

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
/C:/Users/Me/workspaces/scratch/target/classes/     at
java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)   at
java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)   at
java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)   at
scratch.UrlBug.<init>(UrlBug.java:20)   at
scratch.UrlBug.main(UrlBug.java:39)
```

I'm quite prepared to accept the bug is in my code.  However I think this is a problem with URL class and  [Kohsuke](http://www.java.net/blogs/kohsuke) seems to [agree](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/how_to_convert.html)

Comment: What exactly makes you think this is a bug?

Comment: What is the bug/inconsistency you refer to exactly?

Comment: @PaulTomblin If you run the code, you get an exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /C:/src/other/stackoverflow/
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
        at UrlBug.<init>(UrlBug.java:15)
        at UrlBug.main(UrlBug.java:23)

Comment: Yes, because you're passing in a file name as if it were a URL. It is malformed. Where's the bug?

Comment: A URL can be a filename, see RFC 1630 and RFC 1738.  The bug is that getFile() and getPath() return invalid formats for Filenames and Paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to walk the jar directory structure yourself. Java has existing classes designed to handle just this case. To fix your code, you can just use the `toString()` method:

```
new URL(resourceRoot.toString());
```

The "file:/" prefix is the "protocol". Using the `toString()` method guarantees that the "file:/" protocol is prepended to the string. According to the docs:

```
Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path:

     http, https, ftp, file, and jar
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)